# call to undefined method photos() laravel project flyer

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm working on laravel's project flyer and I'm continually getting this error from artisan tinker.

```
 $flyer->photos()->create(['photo' => 'foo.jpg']);
```

> BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate
>       \Database\Query\Builder::photos()'

Here is my Flyer.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Flyer extends Model
{
    public function photos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Photo');
    }
}
```

and here is my `Photo.php` file:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Photo extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'flyer_photos';

    protected $fillable = ['photo'];

    public function flyer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Flyer');
    }
}
```

looks like the method photos() doesn't get recognised or something

Comment: So what is `$flyer` ?

Comment: Kindly post the line that creates `$flyer`

Comment: $flyer = factory('App\Flyer')->create();

Answer (score 0):

From the error description, `$flyer` is not a `Flyer` object, it's an `Illuminate \Database\Query\Builder` object. That's your error. When creating `$flyer`, be sure to use a `get()` or `first()` after building your query.

Comment: this is what i use to create the object    
$flyer = factory('App\Flyer')->create(); and it runs fine but after that i run $flyer->photo()->create(['photo' => 'foo.jpg']); and that's where i  get the error

Comment: Perhaps we need to see the `factory` defined for `App\Flyer`. Do confirm that the `$flyer` created is indeed a `Flyer` object.

Comment: yes it is a flyer object and the factory is a laravel command

Comment: Oh, I do know the `factory` function. It requires that you set up a factory closure function. Was wondering if the issue was from there. I realise now that Laravel might be using a builder to make a query behind the scenes when you call a function